# How to turn off/disable google analytics logging in WSO2CEP-4.1.0 at startup

Tags: google-analytics, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

1. stop firstly CEP
2. find shinding.war (wso2cep-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/shindig.war)
3. in WAR find shinding-extras-VERSION.jar (under WEB-INF/lib) extract JAR
4. go to features.txt and comment

   `#features-extras/com.google.gadgets.analytics/feature.xml`
5. pack again jar (by jar tool cvf jar_name.jar .)
6. redeploy WAR with the new JAR
7. start CEP

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not even a question

Comment: It is a question with answer. Download a fresh version of CEP from WSO2. You will see a lot of google analytics errors on the console saying that a connection could not be established, for example. Whenever you restart the service it will slown down your development as the service waits for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2016-05/msg37827.html) might help you.

According to that,

> To get rid of this error we have to remove google related stuff from
> shindig features.txt file
>
> features-extras/analytics/feature.xml
>
> features-extras/com.google.gadgets.analytics/feature.xml

So, you may give another try with your step 4 adjusted.